# when i am doing ng g compoment newone its not getting updated in app.module.ts

Tags: angular

> i am creating a new component and it mentions that it is added the new component to the module.ts but when i check my module.ts it does display the new component

```
 $ ng generate component newone
      create src/app/newone/newone.component.html (25 bytes)
      create src/app/newone/newone.component.spec.ts (628 bytes)
      create src/app/newone/newone.component.ts (269 bytes)
      create src/app/newone/newone.component.css (0 bytes)
      update src/app/app.module.ts (602 bytes)
```

> this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';


    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

try ou this steps in terminal . This might be issue in version of angular cli

npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

npm uninstall angular-cli @angular/cli -–save-dev

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

## let’s update all the local again packages to the latest ones with this funny utility:

npm install -g npm-check-updates

ncu -u -a --packageFile package.json

rm -rf node_modules

npm install

Comment: when i tried opening the file through notepad its shows the added components, but its doesn't show in visual studio code editor. can i know why?